# Как сделать плавный скролл?

Tags: jquery

Есть [сайт](https://strongpassword.pro/) генератор паролей. Там при нажатии на кнопку идет плавный скролл. Как сделать такой же?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('[data-target]').offset().top
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 50px
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.target {
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.target:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: pink;
}

[data-target] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Клик</button>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target" data-target>Цель</div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
```